# Showing and missing a Flutter button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show the button after certain selections in Flutter, does anyone have an idea? In other words, I want the filtering screen not to pass before I can make a selection?

Comment: There is no way we can help you with such a generic description. Please describe what you want to do in more detail, then describe what parts of that you already *can* do, what your next step is and where you are stuck at exactly. If you have code, post the code you already have and the problem you face with what you want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you need the Visibility Widget in a Stateful Widget to toggle the visibility of your button.
The implementation would look like the following.

```
bool _isVisible = false;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Visibility(
          visible: _isVisible,
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => showFilteringScreen();
            },
            child: Text("Click me"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And somewhere in your Widget where you can detect that the selection was done properly, you just have to call the following method to render the Button.

```
setState(() {
  _isVisible = true;
});
```

Next time, consider adding more informations to your question and some code, it will help people to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never thought I could use a widget like this. Thanks for your labor. :)